# Output of my python list / array is repeating the values. How do I remove this?

Tags: python

I want my code to store the x results in a list. However, it is repeating the value of x's. How do I fix this?

```
list = [1, 3 , 2, 0, 4, 0, 12]
non_zeros = [list for list in list if list != 0]

set_x = []
num_x = 0

for i, (prev_coeff, next_coeff) in enumerate(zip(non_zeros, non_zeros[1:])):
    x = (next_coeff*3) / (prev_coeff*2)
    print(f"x{i + 1} = {x}")
    num_x += 1
    for j in range(num_x):
        set_x.append(x)
print(set_x)
```

My result is:

```
x1 = 4.5
x2 = 1.0
x3 = 3.0
x4 = 4.5
[4.5, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5]
```

How do I set the list to be:

```
[4.5, 1.0, 3.0, 4.5]
```

Comment: `for j in range(num_x): set_x.append(x)` Why are you running this loop? This will basically add one element multiple time and that's what you are getting in the output.

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh i cannot think of other way to append the values of x with the numbers of x's that i get in my loop. how do i fix this though? i'm new to python.

Comment: Just remove the `for j in range(num_x)` loop. Only use `set_x.append(x)`. For appending in a list you don't need to use another loop.

Comment: alright. worked. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you need to adjust your indentation

```
list1 = [1, 3 , 2, 0, 4, 0, 12]
non_zeros = [t for t in list1 if t != 0]

set_x = []
num_x = 0

for i, (prev_coeff, next_coeff) in enumerate(zip(non_zeros, non_zeros[1:])):
    x = (next_coeff*3) / (prev_coeff*2)
    print(f"x{i + 1} = {x}")
    num_x += 1
for j in range(num_x):   #<--- indent this outside of your loop
    set_x.append(x)
print(set_x)
```